# How can I access these data returned by the result_array() function from a PDO query in CodeIgniter?

Tags: sql, arrays, codeigniter, pdo

```
public function get_details($id)
{
    //my query in pdo form getting my records       
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE idno='". $id ."'");

    //check if query is successfull
if($query)
{
    $query->result_array();//get the result through array form
    print_r($query);//prints the array
}
// end if
}//end function
```

The result of the code above is this:
    `CI_DB_pdo_result Object ( [num_rows] => 1 [conn_id] => PDO Object ( ) [result_id] =>       PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT * FROM users WHERE idno='888812' ) [result_array] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [idno] => 888812 [lname] => smith [fname] => john [username] => john [password] => password [usertype] => a [status] => a ) ) [result_object] => Array ( ) [custom_result_object] => Array ( ) [current_row] => 0 [row_data] => )`

usually the result of the `result_array()` function was just the array of the cursor/result query being executed, now I have a problem on how to get my values returned from this kind of result_array() generated with a lot of different data along with it.

usually the result will be `Array([id] => 888812, [lname] => smith, [fname] => john, [username] => john, [password] => password.....)` so now, why is it I get this kind of array displayed above? and How will I be able to access my data?

whenever I access my data like `$query['result_array']` or `$query['idno']` I get this error
`Fatal error: Cannot use object of type CI_DB_pdo_result as array in C:/.........`

Comment: usually the result will be Array([id] => 888812, [lname] => smith, [fname] => john, [username] => john, [password] => password.....) so now, why is it I get this kind of array displayed above? and How will I be able to access my data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query->result_array();//get the result through array form
```

You aren't assigning the returned results of `result_array()` to anything. So when you're running `print_r($query)`, you're doing that on the original query object, not the results. `result_array()` does not change the query object by reference or anything, you need to capture its results.

```
$results = $query->result_array();
print_r($results);
```

Drink some more coffee or something. :-p

Comment: HAHA, I was doing it with $this->db->get() and it was fine with the return $query->result_array(); now with $this->db->query(my query); and using the return $query->result_array it wasnt the same, Thank you very much Sir for your HELP! . more wisdom!

Comment: Sounds like you were using method chaining. Yeah, gotta keep an eye on that, depending on how you chain / create queries. :)

Comment: Rewrite your query to be:  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE idno=?", array($id)); or there's little point in using PDO